# Drawing graph G=(V,E) in R

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I would like to draw standard G=(V,E) graph in R either by ggplot or some R built-in functions.

I have a data frame containing vertices coords:

```
> V
      x        y
1  589.3438 6422.883
2 8762.6921 7789.147
3 7973.0883 4552.745
4 4100.8408 8108.702
5 6049.3329 6547.239
```

and a zero-one symetric matrix representing edges:

```
> E
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    0    0    1    0
 [2,]    0    0    1    0    1
 [3,]    0    1    0    0    1
 [4,]    1    0    0    0    1
 [5,]    0    1    1    1    0
```

I plot vertices using:

```
plotGraph <- function() {
  qplot(x,
        y,
        data=V,
        xlim=c(0,SIZE),
        ylim=c(0,SIZE),
        main="Graph"
  )
}
```

**How could I draw graph edges on the same plot? Or how do I plot a single edge from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2)?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the variable `SIZE` you use in your function?

Comment: Thats a global constant defining whole problem range. Coords are within (0, SIZE) range and naturally I would like the drawing output to contain (show) all vertices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** (July 7, 2017):

Since I have answered the question originally, a new and improved network/graph plotting package, `ggraph`, has been published, and I think it should supersede the options below, so I'm editing my answer to add the `ggraph` option:

First, a bit of manipulation to get the vertices and edges as an igraph graph object:

```r
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggraph)

V <- read.table(text = "x        y
                        589.3438 6422.883
                        8762.6921 7789.147
                        7973.0883 4552.745
                        4100.8408 8108.702
                        6049.3329 6547.239", 
    header = T) %>%
  rownames_to_column("name")

E <- matrix(c(0,    0,    0,    1,    0,
              0,    0,    1,    0,    1,
              0,    1,    0,    0,    1,
              1,    0,    0,    0,    1,
              0,    1,    1,    1,    0), nrow = 5, byrow = T) %>%
  data.frame() %>% 
  rename_all(list(function(x) 1:5)) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "from") %>% 
  gather(to, val, 2:6) %>% 
  filter(val == 1) %>%
  select(from, to)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(E, vertices = V, directed = F)
```

now comes the `ggraph` magic. To illustrate its power, I've mixed and matched various edge and node `geom`s to provide a sampling of what's possible with `ggraph`.

```r
ggraph(g) + 
  geom_edge_link() + 
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name))
#> Using `nicely` as default layout
```

[image]

```r
ggraph(g) + 
  geom_edge_arc() + 
  geom_node_point()
#> Using `nicely` as default layout
```

[image]

```r
ggraph(g) + 
  geom_edge_diagonal() + 
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), color = "blue")
#> Using `nicely` as default layout
```

[image]

---

Original answer:

If using `igraph` is an option, I would recommend it. It's a very useful package when working with graphs. Here's how I would do it using igraph:

```r
library(igraph)

# convert V to a matrix and E to a graph
V <- data.matrix(V)
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(E, mode="undirected")

plot.igraph(g, layout = V)
```

[image: igraph output]

Alternatively, if you want a ggplot-flavored method, you can use `ggnet2` from the `GGally` package:

```r
library(GGally)

V <- data.matrix(V)
# with ggnet2 you don't have to convert E to a graph

ggnet2(net = E, mode = V )
```

[image: ggnet2 output]

Comment: Thats perfect! Thanks so much. Btw there is little typo in first code snippet, there should be: `g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix( ... )`

Comment: @yeedle this is a very detailed answer. Thank you. I'm trying to change the node type to a circle in your first answer. I've tried geom_node_circle() but it gives an error. Can you please let me know how to change the node type and colour settings and edge width?