# How to flip x and y axes in ggraph R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

The first image is a hand drawn (using MS word) image of a graph. The second image is an attempt to generate the same graph using ggraph.

[image]

Following is the code I used to automatically draw the graph when given the node-edge connections (the code was adopted from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332501/drawing-graph-g-v-e-in-r)). I want to move the x and y axis of the ggraph as shown in the hand drawn graph (image 1). Reverse the x axis numbering from top to bottom and move the y axis to the top. How do I go about it?

```
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggraph)

V <- read.table(text = "x        y
                2 1
                4 2
                4 4
                2 5
                6 4
                3 7
                8 6", 
    header = T) %>%
  rownames_to_column("name")

E <- matrix(c(0,    1,    0,    0,    0, 0, 0,
              0,    0,    1,    0,    0, 0, 0,
              0,    0,    0,    1,    1, 0, 0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 1, 0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 0, 1,
              0,    0,    0,    1,    0, 0, 0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    1, 0, 0), nrow = 7, byrow = T) %>%
  data.frame() %>% 
  rename_all(list(function(x) 1:7)) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "from") %>% 
  gather(to, val, 2:6) %>% 
  filter(val == 1) %>%
  select(from, to)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(E, vertices = V, directed = F)

png("C:\\Users\\Yasoda\\Downloads\\rplot.png", width = 450, height = 450)

ggraph(g) + 
  geom_edge_link(edge_width = 1.3) + 
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name),label.r = unit(0.75, "lines"), 
                  label.size = 0.65, label.padding = unit(0.55,"lines"), show.legend = F) +
  ggtitle("My plot") +
  coord_flip() +
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 9), breaks = c(0:9), minor_breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),limits = c(0, 9), breaks = c(0:9), minor_breaks = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() 


dev.off()
```

I tried using scale_x_reverse() but it distorts the layout and gives the warning "Scale for 'x' is already present.Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.". Also I tried the position = "top" option in the scale_y_continuous and it doesn't make a difference either.

Comment: The example seems to need some fixing: `g <- graph_from_data_frame(E, vertices = V, directed = FALSE)` throws an error.

Comment: @JuliusVainora apologies. I have fixed it now. It's the addition of the ID column to the data frame V. I removed that part. Now it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ggraph(g) + 
  geom_edge_link(edge_width = 1.3) + 
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name),label.r = unit(0.75, "lines"), 
                  label.size = 0.65, label.padding = unit(0.55,"lines"), show.legend = F) +
  ggtitle("My plot") +
  coord_flip() +
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +

  # Using scale_x_reverse and swapping the limits
  scale_x_reverse(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(9, 0), breaks = c(0:9), minor_breaks = NULL) + 
  # switching y position to "right" (pre-flip)
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),limits = c(0, 9), breaks = c(0:9), minor_breaks = NULL, position = "right") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]